Selective sync to store only certain blocks
Would it be possible to modify a substrate node to sync only blocks related to a single contract and transactions related to its state?
For example:

Deploy contract A at block 50
Contract A is modified by transaction 1 at block 75
Contract A is modified by transaction 2 at block 123

Our Substrate node db would only hold blocks [50,75,123]
Presumably, block 75 would be unrelated to block 50 without some kind of merkle proof and we would need to store these as well. Now our db would be

Blocks [50,75,123]
Merkle proofs [50-75, 75-123]

Is this at all possible or simply my naive understanding of how the chain actually works?
